# Replicate DocumentDB to a local mongo service

Tags: database, mongodb, amazon-web-services, aws-documentdb

We're setting up a MongoDB cluster with AWS' DocumentDB.

DocumentDB allows to set up replication in the cloud but we also want to have local replicas. Is it possible to have a local replica of the mongo cluster in the cloud?

Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use DocumentDB [Change Streams](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/change_streams.html) to achieve this. In this [GitHub](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-documentdb-samples/tree/master/samples/change-streams) you can find sample implementations of it. In a series of [DocumentDB from the dining table episode 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LlHZSPVBxjY), you can also learn how to use this feature for your goal.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response!

I'm still a little confused as to where can I set the output to? Say I want the output to a MongoDB that sits on 192.162.12.15.

Comment: You can send events to a messaging service (sqs, kinesis, kafka) and implement a client in EC2, on-prem server, or Lambda which consumes the event and insert it in your on-prem MongoDB.